# Tornado render() - Too many arguments

Tags: python, tornado

I'm using `render()` to pass in a url and an additional variable but I get this error:

```
TypeError: render() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

My code is:

```
class CloseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):   
    def get(self):       
        ui=db.users.find_one({"Username": ui0})
        ui1 = ui["Username"]        
        self.render("thanks.html" , ui1)
```

Comment: This is a wild guess. Is it supposed to be `self.render("thanks.html" , Username = ui1)`?

Comment: According to the docs render takes a template_name, pass anything else as a kwarg as @Kevin has suggested. [docs](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.render)

Comment: Thanks yes I needed to have passed it as `self.render("thanks.html" , ui1=ui["Username"] )`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `self.render("thanks.html" , ui1)`.They represent different meaning.The first `ui1` is the template_name and the second `ui1` is the dict:ui1.